# Error when calling a class method from another class

Tags: java, methods

I'm trying to call a class method called drawPyramid that is in a class called Drawer from another class called Main, but I get the following error: Main.java:38: error: cannot find symbol Drawer.drawPyramid(value);

Main class

```
package dsaa.lab01;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    static Scanner scan;

    /***
     * commands:
     * py size
     *   draw a pyramid with size
     * ct size
     *   draw a christmas tree with size
     * ld documentName
     *   load document from standard input line by line. Last line consists of only sequence "eod",
     *   which means end of document
     * ha
     *   halt program and finish execution
     * @param args
     */
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("START");
        scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean halt=false;
        while(!halt) {
            String line=scan.nextLine();
            // empty line and comment line - read next line
            if(line.length()==0 || line.charAt(0)=='#')
                continue;
            // copy line to output (it is easier to find a place of a mistake)
            System.out.println("!"+line);
            String word[]=line.split(" ");
            if(word[0].equalsIgnoreCase("py") && word.length==2) {
                int value=Integer.parseInt(word[1]);
                Drawer.drawPyramid(value);
                continue;
            }
            if(word[0].equalsIgnoreCase("ct") && word.length==2) {
                int value=Integer.parseInt(word[1]);
                Drawer.drawChristmassTree(value);
                continue;
            }
            // ld documentName
            if(word[0].equalsIgnoreCase("ld") && word.length==2) {
                Document.loadDocument(word[1],scan);
                continue;
            }
            // ha
            if(word[0].equalsIgnoreCase("ha") && word.length==1) {
                halt=true;
                continue;
            }
            System.out.println("Wrong command");            
        }
        System.out.println("END OF EXECUTION");
        scan.close();

    }




}
```

Drawer class

```
package dsaa.lab01;

public class Drawer {
    private static void drawLine(int n, char ch) {
        
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(ch);
        }
    }


    public static void drawPyramid(int n) {

        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            drawLine(n-i, '.');
            drawLine(2*i-1, 'X');
            drawLine(n-i, '.');

            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void drawChristmassTree(int n) {
        System.out.println("Christmas Tree");
    }

}
```

I tried different things but it just doesn't work, I was expecting the class Main to call that method correctly.

Comment: Did you save the Drawer class?

Comment: Yes, I saved it

Comment: How do you compile the files? Are you using IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Please add an import statement to the Main class:

```
import dsaa.lab01.Drawer;
```

Comment: You don't need an import since `Drawer` is in the same package as `Main`.

Comment: It is in the same package

Comment: And both classes (Java sources) are in the same directory? Like dsaa/lab01/Main.java and dsaa/lab01/Drawer.java